# rails3 migration to add new column does not save values to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

So, I created the following migration:

```
class AddAclToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :acl, :integer
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :acl
  end
end
```

however, after modifying the various erb files in the view, values entered in edit.html.erb are not saved to the database.

I can manually start SQlite3 and select * the table and see that the column was created but no values are entered.  I can also manually UPDATE or INSERT numbers into the new column which the controller queries and displays correctly.

Any suggestions on what may be wrong with the frameworks udate/save??

-daniel

Comment: Can you pastie the relevant controller, model and view code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if there is a list of `attr_accessible` in your `User` model. If you are using `Devise` like gem/plugin for authentication you would have a list of `attr_accessible` in the model.

Add new attribute (`acl` in your case) to the `attr_accessible` list.

If this is not the case, I would like you to paste your view, controller and model code

Comment: So, as I was copying pasting a PasteBin, I see what you mean about adding the new field to the attribute accessor -- great call.  I'll try this out and get back -- Yes.  That was the trick.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: In rails 4, look in your controller (in your case may be users_controller.rb). At the bottom is a private section with a function requiring an permitting fields. You will note that the permit section does not have this new field. Add it.